# edge.js no response under windows form

Tags: c#, async-await, edgejs

The following gives result after 1-2 seconds:

```
[STAThread]
        static  void Main()
        {
            //                        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            //                        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            //                        Application.Run(new Form1());
            Task mainTask = MainAsync();
            mainTask.Wait();

        }
        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var func = Edge.Func(@"
            var esprima = require('esprima');
            var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');

            var esprimaast = esprima.parse('var a=1;', { loc: true });
            var esprimaStr = stringify(esprimaast, { space: 3 });
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, esprimaStr);
            }
           ");//end Edge.Func

            var result = await func(null);

            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Object myresult = serializer.Deserialize<JSProgram>(result.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(serializer.Serialize(myresult));



        }
```

But when I use an windows form

```
    [STAThread]
    static  void Main()
    {
                               Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                               Application.Run(new Form1());

    }
```

and trigger it under button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Task mainTask = MainAsync();
            mainTask.Wait();
        }

        async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var func = Edge.Func(@"
            var esprima = require('esprima');
            var stringify = require('json-stable-stringify');

            var esprimaast = esprima.parse('var a=1;', { loc: true });
            var esprimaStr = stringify(esprimaast, { space: 3 });
            return function (data, callback) {
                callback(null, esprimaStr);
            }
        ");//end of Edge.Func

            var result = await func(null);

            txtEsprima.Text = result.ToString();
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Object myresult = serializer.Deserialize<JSProgram>(result.ToString());

           txtMe.Text=serializer.Serialize(myresult);



        }
```

There is no reply at all, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've fallen foul of the usual "mix async with `.Result()`/`.Wait()` deadlock" problem.  Your `.Wait()` blocks your WinForms UI thread until the Task is complete.  However, in a Windows message loop context, the way the Task continues is to post a request to execute a continuation delegate to the message loop.  As you've stopped the message loop with the blocking `.Wait()`, you have a deadlock, and it will stay there forever.

To fix, make `button1_Click()` async, and `await mainTask` instead of `Wait()`ing for it.

The reason is works in the first example is you don't have an active message loop yet, so the continuation strategy is different.